# Problems with receiving udp multicast packets on client side

Tags: c, sockets

I have strange problem with multicast server/client application. I wrote simple server and client udp multicast application in C and I tested it using two laptops and one wireless router.Server is connected  with the ethernet cable to the wrt54gl linksys router with 192.168.1.101 IP address. Client  with IP 192.168.1.105 address is connected to the router via wireless interface. They can ping each other. Server is sending UDP packets using sendto function and client is receiving  them using recvfrom function. When I run my server I can see sent udp packet in wireshark destined for multicast group with IP address 226.1.1.1 but on client side I don't receive those packets and also I can't see them in wireshark. I'm pretty sure that code is properly written. Do you have experience with multicast to advice me?

Thank you

Comment: If you ping the multicast group from one computer, does the packet make it to the other one? If not, your problem is in the router.

Comment: Did you clear the "filter multi-cast" setting in your advanced router configuration before doing this?

Comment: Hi guys, I figure out what is the problem....If server and client are in the same subnet multicast is working. But if my server is connected to the public network and my router is connected also to the public network and then I connect client to the lan of router this is not working...they are in different subnets ...is there any option on router (I can install dd-wrt too) to fix this ?

Comment: Problem is solved and it was pretty simple: client was to close to the router so he wasn't able to receive the packets. Multicast is working in local subnet and also in two different subnets, depens on TTL parameter.